# Perl ref() does not print the 'HASH' type

Tags: perl

The following code does not print the 'HASH' type. What is wrong with this code ?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
$prices{'pizza'} = 12.00;
$prices{'coke'} = 1.25;
$prices{'sandwich'} = 3.00;
print ref($prices);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you should put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script (and do that for all the future Perl code as well). After doing so, you will see the following:

```
Global symbol "%prices" requires explicit package name at ./a.pl line 4.
Global symbol "%prices" requires explicit package name at ./a.pl line 5.
Global symbol "%prices" requires explicit package name at ./a.pl line 6.
Global symbol "$prices" requires explicit package name at ./a.pl line 7.
Execution of ./a.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What it means is that you tried to use to separate variables: a `%prices` hash and a `$prices` scalar.

After fixing variable declaration using `my %prices;`, you can get a reference to your `%prices` hash as follows:

```
my $prices_ref = \%prices;
print ref($prices_ref);
```

Answer (score 0):

From formal standpoint, the answer may be shorter:

1. ref($prices) would return 1 if $prices value were a reference to another variable or false otherwise.
2. ref($prices) is the first use of an undeclared variable $prices (previous lines refer to another undeclared variable - hash %prices).
3. The value of $prices is undef and ref($prices) is an empty string.
4. Probably, your idea was to write

   `$prices->{'pizza'} = 12.00;
   $prices->{'coke'} = 1.25;
   $prices->{'sandwich'} = 3.00;
   print ref($prices);`